# Change my redirect code

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, redirect

Below is my Geo Redirect Code that needs change,**What I would like is to add a meta redirect if possible so an eg would be:-

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>GEO Redirect- Working Demo</title>
        <!-- GEO Redirect -->
        <script type="application/javascript">
        function getgeoip(json){
            if(json.country_code == "US"){
                window.location = "http://msn.com/"
    <!-- Can the above line be replaced to: <META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=msn.com'> -->
            } else {
                window.location = "http://google.com/"
    <!-- Can the above line be replaced to: <META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=google.com'> -->
            }
        }
        </script>

        <script type="application/javascript" src="http://www.telize.com/geoip?callback=getgeoip"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Guys any help would be highly appreciated, thanks again.

Comment: It makes no sense why would want to use the meta refresh tag. What is your reason? Problem is by the time your script runs, the meta tag will be run after the time the rendering engine expects it to be there.

Comment: The script works perfect without any meta refesh, its my client who I'm helping needs this specifically hence I thought of asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using jquery;

```
$('head').append('<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=msn.com">');
```

or javascript:

```
var meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.httpEquiv = "Refresh";
meta.content = "0; URL=msn.com";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
```

However, the rendering mode is fixed when the page is loaded, so this will most probably not work as you want it to...

If you're trying to redirect after some time, then you could do this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>GEO Redirect- Working Demo</title>
        <!-- GEO Redirect -->
        <script type="application/javascript">
        function getgeoip(json){
            if(json.country_code == "US"){
                // will redirect to this page, but only after 2 secs.
                setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = "http://msn.com/"; }, 2000);
            } else {
                // will redirect to this page, but only after 2 secs.
                setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = "http://google.com/"; }, 2000);
            }
        }
        </script>

        <script type="application/javascript" src="http://www.telize.com/geoip?callback=getgeoip"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah agreed wait time is a must, but thanks for your assistance :)